# Docker - few containers

Tags: linux, postgresql, nginx, containers, docker

Who could explain how create and connect one to other docker containers.
I need info how connect one container with Nginx to second container with PostgreSQL. How make this relation?
First container with Nginx should get info from second container with Postgre.
I know how create container, how start service but i don't know how create relation.

Thx!

Comment: i tnink this could help https://gist.github.com/jpetazzo/5493295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways, usually involving an external script or other such system to collect information (such as port mappings) from one container, by parsing the [json info](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/commandline/cli/#inspect) or getting the [port mappings](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/commandline/cli/#port), and passing that into a new container that would use it to connect to the first.  There are examples of that in [the documentation](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/) and [examples](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/) section.

With [v0.6.5, released 2013-10-31](http://blog.docker.io/2013/10/docker-0-6-5-links-container-naming-advanced-port-redirects-host-integration/), Docker is adding the ability to coordinate some of this within itself. For now (2013-11-01), the blog post has most of the information on how to use it, but keep you eye on the documention for more.